# Condition for a function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ being right or left-continuous at $a \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory, continuity

I know that $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous if and only if for every convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ the identity holds $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n)$.

Now suppose $f$ is right or left-continuous.

In the case $X=\mathbb R$, why is it then true that if $f$ satisfies $f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n) = f(a)$ for every sequence $(x_n)$ with limit $a \in \mathbb R$ and $x_n \ge a$ then $f$ is right-continuous at $a$ ?

The case $f$ is left-continuous at $a \in \mathbb R$ is analog.

Comment: Hint: $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ left-continuous at $a$ $\iff$ $f_{\mid (-\infty,a]}:(-\infty,a] \to \Bbb R$ left-continuous at $a$ $\iff$ ...

Comment: How can I use the second statement?

Comment: $f_{\mid (-\infty,a]}:(-\infty,a] \to \Bbb R$ left-continuous at $a$ $\iff$ $f_{\mid (-\infty,a]}:(-\infty,a] \to \Bbb R$ continuous at $a$